# Recursos do Windows Com DELPHI

Tags: delphi, windows

Gostaria de Saber como fazer como que meu programa tenha essas opções:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Opções de Desinstalar e Alterar igual mostrado na imagem.

Em Delphi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode criar um instalador para a sua aplicação, por exemplo, com o Inno Setup.
http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

Comment: Por conta do Projeto ser de Alta Complexidade tive que fazer o meu próprio Instalador, porem não tenho ideia de como faço esse tipo de registro no windows para ele ficar no Painel de Controle\Programas\Programas e Recursos com as Opções de Desinstalar / Alterar